# Install an Older Version of Laravel with Sail

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-sail

I have a server that is still running **PHP 7.4.x**

I, therefore, need to install **laravel 8.x** (the current version of laravel is 9.x) with **laravel-sail**. Since I don't have PHP running on the laptop I am using for development, I cannot install laravel with **composer**.

When I run the install command `curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app?with=mysql" | bash` then laravel 9.x is installed.

**How can I make laravel-sail install laravel 8.x?**

Comment: funnily enough if you do `curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app?with=mysql&php=74" | bash` it should install a container with PHP 7.4 and Laravel 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[apokryfos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487813/apokryfos)'s comment got me thinking and I tried the following `curl` command

```
curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app?with=mysql&php=74" | bash
```

That worked. My composer.json looks like this

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.75",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5"
},
```

... and with `sail up`, I have a **Laravel v8.83.9** up and running.

For some reason, the PHP version is still 8.1, but I can change the PHP version in the docker-compose.yml to PHP 7.4 and rebuild. With that, I have **(PHP v7.4.28)**.

**Update:**
I originally thought adding a "laravel=8" to the `curl` command would load laravel in version 8.x, but this had no effect. Adding php=74 is enough to get laravel in version 8.x, but it does not set PHP to version 7.4. That needs to be done in the docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: The written command does not make much difference and the latest version is still installed.

Comment: This did work since when you don't write composer 7.4 when you did the curl, it would fail for just change in composer.json

Answer (score 1):

you can download Laravel 8 or other versions from laravel github repository and replace it with your local project on sail

be careful laravel Sail and related parts (docker-compose,...) should not be deleted

the second way is that clone laravel 8 from github repo and install sail into this project

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#installing-sail-into-existing-applications

laravel 8.6.12 github repo:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/v8.6.12)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't quite solve the problem. I don't have PHP installed on my laptop at all, and without PHP, I cannot use composer to install sail into the project. I am looking for a way to use the 'curl' command to install an older version of laravel. Once I have the docker environment up and running, I will use its PHP.

Comment: With the first way I told you, you do not need to have PHP or any other tool installed on your laptop.

Comment: Yes, thanks. You're right, that will work without PHP. I overlooked that part of your answer. In the meantime, though, I have found a way that seems even more convenient.

Comment: You are right, but the service provider must allow you to choose the version, which is currently not possible in the way you want.
I had this problem too, but for now the best possible way was what I said.