# How to install Laravel 10.x using Sail?

Tags: laravel

I use the command

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
```

And then I get Laravel 11.

How to install Laravel 10.x using Sail?

I tried command

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel example-app "10.*"
```

but this project don't use Sail.

Comment: I know this does not answer your question but in my opinion if you are creating a new project there is absolutely no reason to not use Laravel 11 over 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install an Older Version of Laravel with Sail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71943404/install-an-older-version-of-laravel-with-sail)

Comment: I forgot that I ever made a comment in that question: I guess if you target a PHP version that laravel 11 does not support you might get it to work e.g. `curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app?php=81 | bash` (because Laravel 11 requires PHP 8.2). Of course if you actually want a later version of PHP this won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install manually using "composer create-project" and then install Sail later ([as described here in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/sail#installing-sail-into-existing-applications))

Install laravel/sail package
`composer require laravel/sail --dev`

Publish files
`php artisan sail:install`

Start Sail
`./vendor/bin/sail up`

Answer (score 2):

If you render/download the script used to install Laravel with Sail (like in a browser):

```
https://laravel.build/example-app
```

you will get something like this:

```
docker info > /dev/null 2>&1

# Ensure that Docker is running...
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Docker is not running."

    exit 1
fi

docker run --rm \
    --pull=always \
    -v "$(pwd)":/opt \
    -w /opt \
    laravelsail/php83-composer:latest \
    bash -c "laravel new example-app --no-interaction && cd example-app && php ./artisan sail:install --with=mysql,redis,meilisearch,mailpit,selenium "

cd example-app

# Allow build with no additional services..
if [ "mysql redis meilisearch mailpit selenium" == "none" ]; then
    ./vendor/bin/sail build
else
    ./vendor/bin/sail pull mysql redis meilisearch mailpit selenium
    ./vendor/bin/sail build
fi

CYAN='\033[0;36m'
LIGHT_CYAN='\033[1;36m'
BOLD='\033[1m'
NC='\033[0m'

echo ""

if sudo -n true 2>/dev/null; then
    sudo chown -R $USER: .
    echo -e "${BOLD}Get started with:${NC} cd example-app && ./vendor/bin/sail up"
else
    echo -e "${BOLD}Please provide your password so we can make some final adjustments to your application's permissions.${NC}"
    echo ""
    sudo chown -R $USER: .
    echo ""
    echo -e "${BOLD}Thank you! We hope you build something incredible. Dive in with:${NC} cd example-app && ./vendor/bin/sail up"
fi
```

the line where we have

```
bash -c "laravel new example-app --no-interaction && cd example-app && php ./artisan sail:install --with=mysql,redis,meilisearch,mailpit,selenium "
```

is the actual command to install Laravel.
In this case you can replace it by the composer command to create a Laravel project:

```
bash -c "composer create-project laravel/laravel:^10.0 example-app && cd example-app && php ./artisan sail:install --with=mysql,redis,meilisearch,mailpit,selenium "
```

of course you can also replace/add/remove the services you want in the "--with" parameter.

Finally you only need save the new script content to a file and execute locally.